# Azure AD JWT missing "groups" node when logging into AAD using a Native app type

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory

The JWT that is acquired when logging into a Native App does not emit the "groups" node that the JWT that is acquired when logging into a Web App does.

Both app registrations are configured to emit the groups
 **"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"**

This is an Implicit grant scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

This is for anyone looking to understand the solution later.

After getting more information from @LastTribunal, it turned out that there were 3 separate applications in use (a web app SPA, a .NET based native app and a web api). Manifest for third app, i.e. the web api was missing `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"`

**Bottom line**: Even when a token is acquired from a native application to access a web api, as long as the web api's manifest is configured correctly, the access token does include groups claims.

This is a link to the sample that @LastTribunal was following and having issues with for the native application. [Integrating Azure AD into a Windows desktop application using interactive authentication](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop#integrating-azure-ad-into-a-windows-desktop-application-using-interactive-authentication)

**Initial Answer**

The user you're checking for might be part of 6 or more groups. In case of Implicit grant flows, if the full groups claim would extend the URI fragment beyond the URL length limits, Azure AD sends you an overage claim instead of the "groups" claim.

So you might be getting an overage indicator through a claim like "hasgroups" or "groups:src1" depending on whether length of the token will be an issue or not.

For e.g. In case of Single Page Applications (SPA), you will get back a "hasgroups" claim, while in case of a .NET based native application using ADAL.NET library where token length is not an issue, I have seen "groups:src" being used for overage indication.

Basically you are given a hint that user is part of a lot of groups (currently lot means 6 or more) and you have to make a second call to get the information about all groups that this user is part of.

Microsoft Docs: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims)

[image]

Comment: I would have had this problem in across the board.  I don't have it with Web App.  Same user

Comment: I understand, but token length applies specifically to Implicit Grant flow, web app may not be using the implicit grant flow. If you are using the same user for both cases, it's simple enough to check the token using a tool like https://jwt.ms or https://jwt.io

Comment: Web app IS using Implicit grant

Comment: I don't get any hasGroups node

Comment: and not a `groups:src1` node either? Also, in case of web app where you are getting back the groups, how many groups is the user a part of?

Comment: no mention of group anything in the JWT from native

Comment: ok.. do check how many groups do you get back in case of web app.. and what language/platform are you using to write this native app?

Comment: I only have 4 security groups