# Azure AD and Group-based authorization with token in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

In my Azure AD I have user and group. I want to give an access to users according to a group the belong to.

I successfully implement it in ASP.NET MVC application.
How I set up group claims:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(c => { c.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";});

     services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Admins",
            policyBuilder =>
            {
                policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups",
                    Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSecurityGroup:AdminObjectId"));
            });
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Employees",
            policyBuilder =>
            {
                policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups",
                    Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSecurityGroup:EmployeeObjectId"));
            });
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Managers",
            policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSecurityGroup:ManagerObjectId")));
    });

    services.Configure<AzureADOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
}
```

And if I want to restrict access for non-admin user to Contacts page I do this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "Admins")]
    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

It works
Now the idea is to create an web api controller and restrict access to some of the method.

```
//[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] {"value1", "value2"};
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [Authorize(Policy = "Admins")]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

I use postman. I get an access token:

> POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token

then send

> GET https://localhost/api/values/1

with header **Authorization** and value **Bearer {token}**
but get Unauthorized access (401). (Unprotected https://localhost/api/values works as expected though). I suspect that I pass wrong token, I check it on https://jwt.io/ and it does not contain information about a group the user belongs to. Should I configure it in the code another way? Thanks

**Update 1 (decoded token):**

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "nbCwW11w3XkB-xUaXwKRSLjMHGQ",
  "kid": "nbCwW11w3XkB-xUaXwKRSLjMHGQ"
}.{
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-1835-453d-a552-28feda08393e/",
  "iat": 1544770435,
  "nbf": 1544770435,
  "exp": 1544774335,
  "aio": "42RgYPjkVuw2Z/fJtp+RF/mUp7Z5AQA=",
  "appid": "963418bb-8a31-4c47-bc91-56b6e51181dc",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-1835-453d-a552-28feda08393e/",
  "oid": "0dfb0f07-b6e1-4318-ba33-066e1fc3c0ac",
  "sub": "0dfb0f07-b6e1-4318-ba33-066e1fc3c0ac",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": "xxxxxxxx-1835-453d-a552-28feda08393e",
  "uti": "cxlefO0ABkimo2z-7L0IAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]
```

Comment: Have you configured the app to require groups in the token?

Comment: @juunas No, could you explain how to do it? To add into the manifest "groupMembershipClaims":"SecurityGroup" ?

Comment: @amplifier yes, modifying the app registration manifest to include `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"` should do it. Also, similar to the way you're authorizing based on groups, sometimes it's good to use application roles.. Here are a couple of other SO posts that may be relevant for you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469913/asp-net-mvc-and-azure-active-directory-security-group-based-authorization/52470791#52470791 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883782/azure-ad-jwt-missing-groups-node-when-logging-into-aad-using-a-native-app-type/52884178#52884178

Comment: @rohitsaigal adding group membership claims didn’t help

Comment: @amplifier have you looked at the token claims again in https://jwt.io or https://jwt.ms after changing the manifest? Is there a groups claim but value is empty or there isn't a groups claim at all? Also, one special case is when a user is part of 6 or more groups then you get an overage indicator like `hasGroups` instead of the regular groups claim so check for that as well. If possible, put in a redacted version of your decoded token claims without any sensitive info as part of question..

Comment: How do you get the access token ? Could you please show the post request ?

Comment: @rohitsaigal there isn't a groups claim at all. Each user belongs to only one group

Comment: @nan-yu I mentioned it. POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token with grant_type, clienId and client secret in the body

Comment: @amplifier what is the grant_type ?

Comment: @nan-yu grant_type:client_credentials

Comment: @amplifier , you are using client_credentials flow , it uses app's own credentials instead of impersonating a user, so no user information is included in this scenario ,you should use code flow to get the access token .

Comment: @NanYu Could you clarify please, what's better to use. I'm going crazy with all that ways of login via azure active directory :)  All I want to do is it have a frontend app and separated web api app. Frontend should pass login and password to webapi. Webapi returns token or whatever. WebApi contains different methods with policies based on Azure AD groups. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When using `grant_type` is `client_credentials` , that means you are using the client credentials flow to acquire access token for accessing the resource :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

> > The OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow permits a web service (confidential client) to use its own credentials instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service. In this scenario, the client is typically a middle-tier web service, a daemon service, or web site.

In this scenario ,  the client use its own credentials instead of impersonating a user , no user information/identity is included in this scenario. You should use Code Grant Flow to authorize access to web applications and web APIs using user's identity :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: I didn't find any example where I could pass login and password and received a token back. Could you help please?

Comment: @amplifier ,See code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) , use [OnAuthorizationCodeReceived](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L63) event to get access token for your api .

Comment: But where does the user passes login and password?

Comment: @amplifier , use will be redirected to microsoft's login page to sign-in with their credential , please try that code sample ,