# In an Azure Web App, can you lock specific routes from being accessed externally?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have implemented AAD SSO using react-adal for my React application, but all my node REST endpoints are still accessible via external users & resources.  Does Azure offer any way of securing these routes so that they can not be accessed by anything other than the application itself?

i.e. block external users from access to example.com/get-users/
but allow the application to still have access to this route.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must read/define groups that will be allowed to access that particular route, and set it in your app level. Azure AD only authenticate / return the token with user information (including claims).

More info:

https://blog.bitscry.com/2020/04/21/azure-active-directory-group-based-authorization/

[Azure AD and Group-based authorization with token in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761796/azure-ad-and-group-based-authorization-with-token-in-web-api)

Comment: Sorry I am not quite clear - will this allow group access to a route without having to authenticate the token within the application?

Comment: no, users will need to authenticate in order to access the application, and then, only members of a particular group will be able to access the specified route

Comment: In other words, make external users part of an "external" group, then block this access or to the opposite, only allow access to "internal" group members

Comment: So in my application authentication is handled initially by "react-adal", requiring the user to be signed into an account within our organization to gain access to the UI.   If I can allow public access to that route (since the application requires authentication) & allow only internal organization access to the API routes that would be exactly what I am trying to achieve.   Will assigning groups to a route achieve this?  Also where can I access that interface as I didn't see it mentioned in docs. Thanks so much Thiago!

Comment: you're mixing the concepts of authentication and authorization. Your app must be protected to avoid public access on protected routes (authentication). Your UI must call an API which will validate if user is authenticated, then, if he/she can access the route (authorization)